# Conditional Formatting of Time

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and thanks in advance for any advice that can be provided. I have written the below VBA code and cannot get it to recognize time >= 20min, or < 20min. Basically, what I am trying to get to work is subtracting two time values from each other, get the difference in one cell, and then highlight any cells >= 20 mins yellow, and < 20mins in red. I have set the code up to iterate down rows so am not sure if this is the problem. See code below.

```
Sub Calculations()

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value


If Cells(i, 7).Value >= 0.0138 Then
Cells(i, 7).Font.ColorIndex = True
Cells(i, 7).Font.ColorIndex = 3
   ElseIf Cells(i, 7).Value < 0.0138 Then
   Cells(i, 7).Font.ColorIndex = 1
   Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 27

   i = i + 1
   End If
   Loop

   End Sub
```

Thus far, it only calculates down to a certain row and then locks up giving me a run time error of "ColorIndex" of Object not found. I tried using 0.0138 to represent 20 minutes, but still have had no luck. Note: When I entered a value of "20" it calculates all the differences, but of course highlights everything yellow. Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Comment: What is `Cells(i, 7).Font.ColorIndex = True` intended to accomplish?

Comment: My apologies it should read Cells(I, 7).Font.Bold = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop only increases `i` if the difference is less than 20 minutes. Move `i = i + 1` outside the If ... ElseIf ... End If.

```
Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value

    If Cells(i, 7).Value >= timeserial(0, 20, 0) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Font.Bold = True
        Cells(i, 7).Font.ColorIndex = 3
   ElseIf Cells(i, 7).Value < timeserial(0, 20, 0) Then
       Cells(i, 7).Font.ColorIndex = 1
       Cells(i, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
   End If

   i = i + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Perfection! I definitely have a lot to learn! Thank you very much for your help!